# $AC_\omega$ is weaker than $AC$, though not provable in ZF without $AC$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, axioms

According to the [wikipedia article on the Axiom of countable choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice),

> The axiom of countable choice ($AC_ω$) is strictly weaker than the axiom of dependent choice (DC), (Jech 1973) which in turn is weaker than the axiom of choice (AC). Paul Cohen showed that $AC_ω$ is not provable in Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory (ZF) without the axiom of choice (Potter 2004).

But if $AC$ is required to prove $AC_ω$, in what sense is it weaker?

Answer (score 4):

Weaker here means that it does not prove as much. Since $\sf AC$ proves $\sf AC_\omega$, it also proves everything that follows from $\sf AC_\omega$. On the other hand, $\sf AC_\omega$ does not prove $\sf AC$.

So by weaker we mean, here, $$\{\varphi\mid\sf ZF+AC_\omega\vdash\varphi\}\subsetneq\{\varphi\mid ZF+AC\vdash\varphi\}.$$

Comment: What is an example of a $\varphi$ that is in the second set but not in the first?

Comment: $\sf AC$ itself...

Comment: Thank you Asaf. Is $AC$ the only one?

Comment: Zorn's Lemma, Dependent Choice, infinitely many other things.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: *infinitely many other things* --- Which now raises the questions of which infinities . . . (I'm guessing it's actually a proper class of other things, at least if fairly strong equivalence between different things is not invoked)

Comment: @Dave: Formally speaking, those sets are defined in the meta-theory, and they are just countable. Internally, yes, a proper class.